# Using isoformat is neglecting seconds with zero value

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am receiving a datetime string which I am converting into python datetime.
My objective was to add 1 second to this datetime.

```
def modify_date_by_1_second(date):
    if date!="":
        try:
            date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
            date_time_obj = date_time_obj + timedelta(seconds=1)
            return date_time_obj.isoformat()[:-3]+'Z'
        except Exception as e:
            return None  
    else:
        return None
```

The above function gives result:

**Passed Case:**

```
Input = "2017-09-15T18:30:15.000Z"
Output = "2017-09-15T18:30:16.000Z"
```

**Failed Case:**

```
Input = "2017-09-15T18:30:00.000Z"
Output = "2017-09-15T18:30Z"
```

I checked by printing the `date_time_obj` object, it outputs `datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 29, 18, 30)`

Here seconds are not mentioned.

Is there any way to achieve this for this specific kind of input?

Comment: You can specify `timespec` keyword to `.isoformat`, e.g. set it to "seconds" and the output string will always have them (but not more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is YOU that is stripping the seconds off, with your `[:-3]`.

Per the documentation, the `.isoformat` method does not include the microseconds if the value is 0.  Perhaps you need to check the length of the string before you whack off your characters.

Just to elaborate, if the datetime value includes any microseconds at all, the return is

```
2017-09-15T18:30:15.000001
```

Which you truncate to:

```
2017-09-15T18:30:15.000Z
```

But if the microseconds value is zero, `isoformst` returns this:

```
2017-09-15T18:30:15
```

which you truncate to

```
2017-09-15T18:30Z
```

Comment: I am talking about seconds not microseconds, as I have told I have printed datetime object for 2017-09-15T18:30:00.000Z but it does not include 0 seconds in it.

Comment: @HemantSah what do you get if you don't use `[:-3]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's 2017-09-15T18:30:01, I got the issue now, thanks